# How can I optimize this simple script?

Tags: php, javascript, html, optimization, redundancy

Actually I have this piece of HTML code

```
<form method=POST action=dosomething.php>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>My account</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for=email>e-mail</label> 
                <span>
                    <?=$account->email?>
                    (<a name="change">change</a>)
                </span>
                <span name="ph">
                    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="new email" type=email>
                    <br>
                    <button name="change_email">change</button> or <a name="cancel">undo</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for=foo>foo</label>  
                <span>
                    <?=$account->foo?>
                    (<a name="change">change</a>)
                </span>
                <span name="ph">
                    <input id="foo" name="foo" type=text>
                    <br>
                    <button name="change_foo">change</button> or <a name="cancel">undo</a>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I've repeated `<li> ... </li>` section only 2 times, but they are repeated various times, and you can notice there is a part that is the same for all.

---

I use this JavaScript in order to achieve a very simple thing: show/hide two `<span>`s.

```
window.onload = function () { 
/* email */
document.getElementsByName('change')[0].onclick = function () {
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementsByName('ph')[0].style.display = 'block';
}
document.getElementsByName('cancel')[0].onclick = function () {
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByName('change')[0].parentNode.style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementsByName('change')[0].parentNode.style.width = '100%';
}

/* social id */
document.getElementsByName('change')[1].onclick = function () {
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementsByName('ph')[1].style.display = 'block';  
}
document.getElementsByName('cancel')[1].onclick = function () {
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByName('change')[1].parentNode.style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementsByName('change')[1].parentNode.style.width = '100%';        
}

/* avatar */
document.getElementsByName('change')[2].onclick = function () {
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementsByName('ph')[2].style.display = 'block';  
}
document.getElementsByName('cancel')[2].onclick = function () {
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByName('change')[2].parentNode.style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementsByName('change')[2].parentNode.style.width = '100%';        
}

/* shout */
document.getElementsByName('change')[3].onclick = function () {
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementsByName('ph')[3].style.display = 'block';  
}
document.getElementsByName('cancel')[3].onclick = function () {
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByName('change')[3].parentNode.style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementsByName('change')[3].parentNode.style.width = '100%';        
}
}
```

This is sooooo LONG ... and repetitious.
As you can see, the only part that changes is `getElementsByName('change')[aNumber]`.

My question is:
**How can I eliminate redundancy?**

A little note: I'd like to see jQuery solutions, but I would prefer to use pure JS.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in JQuery you could use the `.each()` but I think you'd need to change the markup to use `class` instead of `name` because I don't know of a way to use name as a selector. If there is a way, please tell me!

```
$('.change').each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(){
      // Click function for 'change'
   });
});

$('.cancel').each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(){
      // Click function for 'cancel'
   });
});
```

Comment: I don't like jQuery, but ultimately I've chosen this solution. Thanks to everybody!

Comment: Thanks for choosing my solution, but can I ask why you don't like JQuery and if you don't like it, why did you choose it? Just curious is all!

Comment: I don't like frameworks in general because are evil for learning purposes, but this time I've decided to bend the rule. That's all :)

Comment: Fair enough, although using a framework such as jquery doesn't necessarily mean you can get away without knowing how javascript works. It's best to know WHY and HOW jquery is doing what it is in order to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

Give them all the same class.

Use `document.getElementsByClassName`

For example:

```
var clickables = document.getElementsByClassName('clickme');
for(var i = 0; i < clickables.length; i++){
     clickables[i].onclick = function(){
           //some click fn
     }
}
```

Comment: It should be `getElementsByClassName` and it is not supported in IE before 9.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly simplify things with a couple loops:

```
elements = document.getElementsByName('change');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function() {
        document.getElementsByName('ph')[i].style.display = 'block';  
    }
}

cancels = documents.getElementsByName('cancel');

for (i = 0; i < cancels.length; i++) {
    cancels[i].onclick = function () {
        this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
        cancels[i].parentNode.style.display = 'block';
        cancels[i].parentNode.style.width = '100%';
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this give problems with the scoping of `i`?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately. Wasn't intended to be a magic bullet answer, but an example of how things could be simplified.

Comment: Does anyone know of some trick to get around the scoping problem?

Comment: Use jquery for this sort of thing, with the `.bind()` option.

Comment: I like your solution but unfortunately doesn't work for me :( `document.getElementsByName('ph')[i].style.display = 'block';` this don't work